# Saving Android Activity or Fragment state using Parceler

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-savedstate, parceler

I am using [parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) library . I have made an complex object with this . As it says it makes the object parcelable , so I want to use it for saving fragment state .

Here is my model

```
@Parcel
public class Example {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Example() {}

    public Example(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

And in my fragment  I have this

```
   ArrayList<Example> exampletLists;
```

But when I try to put it in `onSaveInstanceState`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("EXAMPLE_LIST",exampletLists); //this is what I want to do , but I can't 
}
```

And I want to get the value in onCreate Like

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    exampletLists = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(EXAMPLE_LIST);
 }
```

How can I achieve this with this libray ?

Comment: @shurvo Can you explain your problem briefly?

Comment: I have a recycler view , which is showing some item via web service . Each time I rotate the screen , the web service is called again . In order to avoid that , I have to save state  . And the variable I want to set  is the List of Example . So I have to make Example class Parcelable , so I can put it into outState.putParcelableArrayList ,  I have made the class Example Parcelable using this library , I can't put it inside outState.putParcelableArrayList

Comment: What error are you getting in putParcelable?

Comment: It is saying exampletLists must be extent Parcelable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parceler can wrap ArrayLists, so what you can do is use the `Parcels.wrap()` and `Parcels.unwrap()` methods when writing and reading your `savedInstanceState:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("EXAMPLE_LIST", Parcels.wrap(exampletLists));
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        exampletLists = Parcels.unwrap(savedInstanceState.getParcelable(EXAMPLE_LIST));
    }
}
```